# Like operator teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, teradatasql

I am trying to find the data using like operator. I am new into it and unsure how to find data. Below is input and output that I require but with my query that I am getting dropdown also which I don't want.

Input:

```
drop
drop1
drop15
drop20
drop30
dropdown
```

output:

```
drop
drop1
drop15
drop20
drop30
```

I have tried

```
select * From test where input like 'drop%'
```

but in output getting dropdown as well which is not required.Can someone help.

Comment: How did you identify that `dropdown` is not what you want? Add formalization of this restriction to your query

Comment: @astentx- Just need with drop and drop followed by number.

Comment: Possibly `... and (trycast(substring(input, 4) as integer) is null or input = 'drop')`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `NOT LIKE` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE input LIKE 'drop%' AND input NOT LIKE 'dropdown%'
```

Comment: Thank you Tarikh.Just checking if there is any way to find out if it's like drop or drop followed by number.

Answer (score 1):

As Teradata supports [regular expression](https://docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageCloud-Lake/SQL-Reference/SQL-Functions-Expressions-and-Predicates/Regular-Expression-Functions/REGEXP_SIMILAR/REGEXP_SIMILAR-Result-Type), you can use regexp_similar  to find the patterns you like.

With https://regex101.com/ you can test patterns

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE regexp_similar(input, 'drop[0-9]*') = 1;
```

Comment: Should have an end of match anchor `$` to prevent `drop123any`

Comment: Thank you,just checking if there is anything we can do with normal like .Example if its like  'drop' or like 'drop followed by any number' not sure how to write that.Also i tried regexp_like it doesn't look correct.There is regexp_similar but not regexp_like

Comment: no the link shows what teradata supports regexp_similar doesn't belong to it, the "normal" like will not do it, if there should only be numbers following a text

Comment: Your link is showing syntax for Presto, but Teradata is PCRE-compatible and there's no `regexp_like`. In your case it's `WHERE regexp_similar(input  'drop[0-9]*') = 1`

Comment: @Sak after reading dnoeth comment i corrected my answer

Comment: And for regexp_similar, the pattern must match the entire string - in other words it behaves as if the pattern starts with ^ and ends with $ (whether explicitly specified or not)

Comment: @dnoeth-thank you...will it work in case we have the data like abc_test_drop1,cde_drop etc? if we give like this regexp_similar(tablename , '%_Drop[0-9]*') = 1?